# How to ensure that an oddly form block of text is equal in width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
<div>
  <div>Top Text</div>
  <div><span>A</span><span>B</span><span>C</span></div>
</div>
```

The idea is to have something like:

```
Top Text
A   B  C
```

Where `Top Text` is always lined up with the starting and ending text on the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, flexbox can do the job:

```css
.box {
  display:inline-block; /* fit content */
}

.box > div:last-child {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>Top Text</div>
  <div><span>A</span><span>B</span><span>C</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works when the bottom text are shorter than the top. What will happen if the top text is shorter?

Comment: @free_lions_n_tigers_from_cages I don't know, you didn't mention this requirement in your quesiton